# 'Add to Calendar' is absent in Inbox by Gmail

Tags: google-calendar, inbox-by-gmail

When I used Gmail and got email with appointment and hover mouse on date, I got the message:

[image: Add to Calendar]

But now in Inbox by Gmail I don't have this option. Is it possible to add it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately this hasn't been implemented yet in Google Inbox. They recommend that if you want the feature, provide your feedback by following [these steps](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067592?hl=en).

> 1. Go to the area in Inbox that you're having trouble with. We'll take a screenshot of the page, and it helps if we can see the problem. You can choose not to include the screenshot.
> 2. Go to the main menu in the top left [image: Main menu].
> 3. Scroll to the bottom and choose **Help and feedback**.
> 4. Click **Send feedback**.
>
> In your feedback, try to share as much detail about the problem or suggestion as you can.

[Source](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/PaidAbIPHck)

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely pester Google to implement this as described in the other answer, but in the meantime if you need access to the old Gmail you can access it from the Gmail link on the sidebar menu.